# SVM in R takes a long time and it didin´t execute

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

My data.frame is called "df_dummy" and it has 77000 rows and 57 columns. I am doing this code in R and It takes a long time to execute, it always loads but it never finishes executing.

```
library(e1071)

tuning.lin <- tune("svm", MH7A ~ ., data = df_dummy, 
               kernel = "radial", 
               ranges = list(cost = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 15)), 
               scale = TRUE)

summary(tuning.lin)
```

Does anyone know then how I can then make the svm model to my data frame made up of dummy variables?

Comment: Note that the name of the famous software is R not r. I edited!

Comment: Ok, sorry thank you so much

Comment: See also: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/why-does-training-an-svm-take-so-long-how-can-i-speed-it-up